# Variables for controlling array iteration on iOS 5

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios6, objective-c-blocks

I have seen somewhere that the following three codes are doing the same thing.

Using loops:

```
BOOL stop = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; i < [theArray count] ; i++) {
    NSLog(@"The object at index %d is %@",i,[theArray objectAtIndex:i]);
    if (stop)
        break;
}
```

Using fast enumeration:

```
int idx = 0;
BOOL stop = 1;

for (id obj in theArray) {
    NSLog(@"fast emuration approch @ x %d is %@",idx,obj);
    if (stop)
        break;
    idx++;
}
```

Using blocks:

```
[theArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){

    NSLog(@"the block approch at x %d is %@",idx,obj);
}];
```

But what I don't understand is -

1. How can I set stop from outside in the block approach?
2. How can I set idx in the block approach?
3. BOOL declaration is unusual in block approach .why? (Because I am not able to change the value within the block also , is it because of such declaration?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can only change the value pointed to by `stop` within the block - but as far as semantics are concerned, you can't do any different in the other approaches, either, unless you're using a variable with broader scope that indicated by your sample code and manipulating it on another thread.
2. You can't. The code you write in the block is your loop body, essentially, and `idx` and `stop` are passed from the calling context of the block, where they serve to control the iteration within that context. I mean, within the implementation of the `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` method, it sets up locals `idx` and `stop` as you do in the fast enumeration method, and passes them as arguments to the block.
3. You receive a pointer to a `BOOL` you can change the value that the caller sees. That is, from within the block you set `*stop` to `YES` and the implementation of `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` will see that its local variable `stop` has been set to `YES`. This is the typical way of returning multiple arguments by reference in C.

Comment: Thanks carl ... but when we set i ... we initialize the value of it ... here I am not able to initialize the value ... when I do that in argument , it is giving me warning .

Comment: and it is not allowing me to change the value of BOOL inside the pointer ... I don't understand why is it declared as a pointer there?

Comment: I'm sorry, can you phrase it differently? What argument? And regarding your second question - when you need to stop iteration, do `*stop = YES;` They give you a pointer so you can manipulate the value of a variable in the calling context, like you would in a function call.

Comment: okay , That worked . But carl , why * is there ? in general we declare bool as `BOOL stop` . why is that thing is different here .

Comment: and regarding idx, what if I want to start idx from say no 5 .. when I am doing this `[theArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx = 5, BOOL *stop)` . . but I can't do this because it is giving me a warning

Comment: You can't do this, because enumerateObjectsWithBlock enumerates all of the objects. The block is **not** setting up your loop initialization, but rather the code executed per iteration. The arguments the block takes are the variables being used in the calling context to control the enumeration. You'll need to either `continue` for `idx < 4` or use different enumeration method to do what you want.

Comment: Carl then , should I phrase it like ... whenever In block (or anywhere in multiple argument in Obj-C ) , you should declare bool as *BOOL ??

Comment: @SunTzu no - whenever you must change a value in the calling context for a C function, C block, or Objective-C method, without returning a value, that function, block, or method must take an argument that's a pointer to the variable holding the value in the calling context. Does that make sense? It is called 'passing by reference'. See http://www.cs.utah.edu/~germain/PPS/Topics/C_Language/c_functions.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
__block bool stop = YES;
__block NSUInteger idx = 0;

[theArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj){

    NSLog(@"the block approch at x %d is %@",idx,obj);
    idx++;

}];
```

Comment: Hey , I can also do this ... I can also declare the variable outside and can also perform the operation as you stated ... short and sweet .. great .. thanks :)